# Jekyll change blog permalink with pagination

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have my blog page like this: `pages -> blog -> index.html`. I don't use a permalink in the `index.html` file to change the URL.

In my `_config.yml` I have this: `paginate_path: "/pages/blog-posts/page:num"` to point to the `index.html` file and add the page numbers if a page is changed.

This now adds the `/pages/blog/` to the URL when I have multiple pagination pages.

How can I create a permalink fix and remove the `/pages/` from the permalink structure, i.e I only get `/blog/page-number` in the permalink?

Comment: Try: paginate_path: "/blog/page:num". Make sure your index.html is located in the blog directory at the root level (i.e., /blog/index.html), not under pages/blog.

Comment: Great thx that worked. Moving the blog index, out from the pages folder.